# What causes this weird shape through frosted glass?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, refraction, popular-science

I was looking at my frosted window and found that the light behind it from the neighbors house looked like this:

[image]

Behind the frosted glass is simply an ordinary CFL bulb. The frosting pattern on the glass is like a bunch of small squares:

[image]

What is causing this unusual shape to appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is a direct result of refraction (not diffraction).

There is a repeating pattern in the "frosting" of the glass; this is like a bunch of small lenses. Now when a ray of light is incident on a particular point, it will be refracted through a certain angle, depending on the shape.

What you are seeing is the sum of these deflections - when you look a little bit down from the source, you see the bit of light that was refracted up; when you look up from the source, you will see the light that was shining down, etc.

One way you can convince yourself that this is the right explanation: take a laser pointer and shine it through the glass (preferably from a little distance, so the spot will be about as big as one "repeat pattern" of the frosting). Put a white sheet behind the glass, and take a picture of the pattern.

I predict it will look a lot like what you are seeing here (except it will all be one color - whatever the color of your laser pointer is). And if you repeat with a different color (wavelength), you will get the same pattern (shape and size) which confirms this is not diffraction. Diffraction would result in different size patterns for different wavelengths.

**UPDATE**
@Ruslan actually [did](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/521568/what-causes-this-weird-shape-through-frosted-glass/522029#comment1178518_522029) the experiment I suggested, and asked that I edit the results into this answer. So with thanks, here it goes:

Using a piece of frosted glass similar to the one shown in the original post, he obtained three different pictures. The first shows what a white light looked like through the glass - clearly a similar pattern to the one OP saw:

[image]

The second was the result of shining a violet (405 nm) laser pointer through the glass: the refracted light shows a similar pattern:

[image]

Finally, using a red laser results in the same pattern (size) even though the wavelength is 50% longer. If this was diffraction, the pattern would have been correspondingly larger:

[image]

All this seems to confirm the explanation.

Comment: Can you reproduce the image using a computer simulation, or the experiment you suggest?

Comment: @sammygerbil I have exactly the same kind of glass as the OP (maybe a bit different aspect ratio of the pyramids' sides), and I have tried this with two real laser pointers: [405 nm](https://i.imgur.com/7xKcnFB.jpg) and [640 nm](https://i.imgur.com/euW0BSg.jpg). Note how the size of the pattern is the same, despite the wavelengths differing by a factor of 1.58×. The shape of the patterns does match what I see from a hand light ([here's a photo](https://i.imgur.com/vwge3gO.jpg)).

Comment: @Ruslan You should post these images as an answer, along with one of the pattern on the glass.

Comment: @sammygerbil well they are just an illustration for Floris's answer. I'd rather have this answer edited to include them (but editing them in myself would be too intrusive, so it's better to leave it to post author).

Comment: @Ruslan thanks so much for doing this experiment. I have added (cropped versions of) your pictures into the post. Please confirm you’re OK with that.

Comment: Completely OK (up to my tiny edit).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I still have a doubt: if the refraction is supposed to occur along up-down and left-right, what is causing the diagonal corners in the hypotrochoid-like interior shape?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal the shape of the little rectangles in your window is not "just" up-down or left-right. It's a fully 3D shape and will cause refraction in all directions.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal you'd get mostly up-down and left-right patterns if the pyramids in the glass pattern had flatter faces and sharper edges. But, since it's glass, and the pattern elements are quite small, the pyramids are actually smoother, a bit rounded.